# Android app freezes while WebView inflating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-animation, android-threading

In my app I have some fragments and I switch between them with this nice animation:

```
activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            ?.setCustomAnimations(
                R.anim.slide_in_from_right,
                R.anim.slide_out_to_left,
                R.anim.slide_in_from_left,
                R.anim.slide_out_to_right)

            ?.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, articleContentFragment)
            ?.addToBackStack(null)
            ?.commit()
```

Inside of every fragment I have a RecyclerView with several types of items e.g. TextViews or ImageViews.
And it works fine, **but**

when I added a WebView as one of the types of my RecyclerView items, nice animation of fragment transaction started to freeze the first time I open the fragment. The cause is inflating of WebView.

How can I inflate view in background thread or maybe there are any better solutions?

**(It still works fine in RecyclerViews, which do not inflate WebView as an item)**

My Adapter:

```
class ArticleContentAdapter(
    context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleContentAdapter.BaseViewHolder<*>>() {

    companion object {
        private const val headerType = 1
        private const val paragraphType = 2
        private const val codeSnippetType = 3
        private const val imageType = 4
    }

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var articlePieces = ArrayList<ArticlePiece>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<*> {
        return when (viewType) {
            headerType -> ArticleHeaderViewHolder(
                inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.article_header_item,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
            paragraphType -> ArticleParagraphViewHolder(
                inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.article_paragraph_item,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
            codeSnippetType -> ArticleCodeSnippetViewHolder(
                inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.article_code_snippet_item,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
            imageType -> ArticleImageViewHolder(
                inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.article_image_item,
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            )
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type.")
        }
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (articlePieces[position]) {
            is ArticleHeader -> headerType
            is ArticleParagraph -> paragraphType
            is ArticleCodeSnippet -> codeSnippetType
            is ArticleImage -> imageType
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type of data $position.")
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = articlePieces.size

    internal fun addArticlePieces(articlePieces: List<ArticlePiece>) {
        this.articlePieces = getAllSortedPieces(this.articlePieces, articlePieces)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun getAllSortedPieces(
        formerPieces: List<ArticlePiece>,
        newPieces: List<ArticlePiece>
    ): ArrayList<ArticlePiece> {
        val allSortedPieces = ArrayList<ArticlePiece>()
        allSortedPieces.addAll(formerPieces)
        allSortedPieces.addAll(newPieces)
        allSortedPieces.sortBy { A -> A.positionInArticle }
        return allSortedPieces
    }

    abstract class BaseViewHolder<T>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        abstract fun bind(item: T)
    }

    class ArticleHeaderViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        BaseViewHolder<ArticleHeader>(itemView) {
        private val articleHeader: TextView = itemView.header

        override fun bind(item: ArticleHeader) {
            articleHeader.text = item.getEssentialDataOfPiece()
        }
    }

    class ArticleParagraphViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        BaseViewHolder<ArticleParagraph>(itemView) {
        private val articleParagraph: TextView = itemView.paragraph

        override fun bind(item: ArticleParagraph) {
            val text = "\t ${item.getEssentialDataOfPiece()}"
            articleParagraph.text = text
        }
    }

    class ArticleCodeSnippetViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        BaseViewHolder<ArticleCodeSnippet>(itemView) {
        private val webView: WebView = itemView.webView
        private val loadingPlaceholder: LinearLayout = itemView.loadingPlaceholder
        private val noInternetConnectionPlaceholder: LinearLayout =
            itemView.noInternetConnectionPlaceholder

        override fun bind(item: ArticleCodeSnippet) {

            val codeSnippetController = CodeSnippetController(
                item,
                webView,
                loadingPlaceholder,
                noInternetConnectionPlaceholder
            )

            if (item.viewHeight != 0 || item.viewHeight != 1) {
                webView.layoutParams.height = item.viewHeight
                loadingPlaceholder.layoutParams.height = item.viewHeight
                noInternetConnectionPlaceholder.layoutParams.height = item.viewHeight
            }

            codeSnippetController.loadCodeSnippet()
        }
    }

    class ArticleImageViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        BaseViewHolder<ArticleImage>(itemView) {
        private val imageView: ImageView = itemView.imageView
//        private val loadingPlaceholder: LinearLayout = itemView.loadingPlaceholder
//        private val noInternetConnectionPlaceholder: LinearLayout =
//            itemView.noInternetConnectionPlaceholder

        override fun bind(item: ArticleImage) {
            Picasso.get().load(item.url).into(imageView)
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<*>, position: Int) {
        val piece = articlePieces[position]
        when (holder) {
            is ArticleHeaderViewHolder -> holder.bind(piece as ArticleHeader)
            is ArticleParagraphViewHolder -> holder.bind(piece as ArticleParagraph)
            is ArticleCodeSnippetViewHolder -> holder.bind(piece as ArticleCodeSnippet)
            is ArticleImageViewHolder -> holder.bind(piece as ArticleImage)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try this, Add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to your manifest, either for the <activity> or the <application>.

Comment: this didn't help

Comment: Could you please add the code of your Recyclerview Adapter.

Comment: added.
nothing special in adapter...